# File.delete() deleting target file only at random times

Tags: java, java-io

I'm trying to delete a file in a folder and the folder itself but it only deletes the folder at random times. Why does it happen?
If I keep mashing the delete button it eventually gets deleted.

```
private void deleteCourseButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    File dltcycle = new File(C.viewcoursedirectory);
    System.out.println(dltcycle.getAbsolutePath());
    String[] cycle = dltcycle.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < cycle.length; i++) {
        File dlt = new File(C.viewcoursedirectory + "\\" + cycle[i]);
        System.out.println(C.viewcoursedirectory + "\\" + cycle[i]);
        System.out.println(dlt.getAbsolutePath());
        dlt.delete();
    } 
    dltcycle.delete(); 
 }
```

Expected result is for the folder in the directory to be deleted consistently.
Not at random times after mashing the delete button. I'm sorry if the code block looks ugly, I don't really know how to format it. I don't know why the "{" and "}" are not appearing in the code block :X.

Comment: you can only delete an empty directory with ``File#delete``. Additionally, you should check the return value of ``File#delete`` (a boolean indicating if successfully deleted). Also, a good library to ease file manipulation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory(java.io.File)

Comment: I made it so it deletes the contents of the folder before deleting the folder. But even so it only works sometimes. What's puzzling is that it works only sometimes and not fail all the time.

Comment: you should check the boolean returned by ``delete``: if ``false``, the delete did not succeed (yea I know it sucks, it should throw exceptions instead...)

Comment: You can use both file.delete() and file.deleteOnExit().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for such behavior is a leaked stream. If you, for example, write a file using a FileOutputStream and somehow you do not close it,it will be eventually closed when it's reference gets garbage collected.

Check (if you open the file with either input or output streams) if the stream is always closed.

Comment: Yep, one of them weren't closed properly.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using *Files.delete(Path)* instead. This method throws an IOException so you can see why the deletion failed instead of just getting an unhelpful boolean back.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)

You can get the Path of the file via File.toPath() (so, 'Path p = dlt.toPath()').

Just catch and log the exception to see why the deletion is failing